# Is "Five dollars is all I have" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-formation

I want to emphasize that I only have 5 dollars, so can I use the sentence:

> Five dollars **is** all I have.

Or must it be:

> Five dollars **are** all I have.

Please give the explanation as well.

Comment: Yep, "is all" is the idiomatic way to say it.  The money is regarded as a single entity, just like "This block of gold is all I have."

Comment: Similar to *6 weeks is/are  all I have*. Both are acceptable, depending on whether you consider 5 dollars/6 weeks to be one unit or separate units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the context. If we refer to five dollars as a single entity, then the verb that follows must be singular. If we refer to "five dollars" as five separate pieces of 1 dollar , then the verb must be plural.

Comment: True, but the idiomatic usage in most circumstances is to refer to a quantity of money as a single entity, while referring to five dollar bills separately would be a usage that would only apply in highly unusual circumstances.